# JS class method in a setInterval doesn't work

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have this simple example with a class with a setInterval that calls main() every 5 seconds.
When it comes to call print() it returns me TypeError: this.print is not a function. And I'm really stuck. Why if I call main() without setInterval it works smoothly but with setInterval it fails? It's weird.
Any workaround to call main() periodically without this issue?

```
"use strict";

class test {
  constructor() {
      this.interval = setInterval(this.main, 5000);
  }

  print(){
      console.log('Teeeessssttt');
  }

  main(){
      this.print();
  }
}

const a = new test();
```

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
this.interval = setInterval(this.main.bind(this), 5000);
```

Comment: Can you give a few explanations?

Comment: Thank, that worked. I'll study more about .bind because it is not yet clear why that works :)

Comment: Also read the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) documentation. In your original code `this.main` was being called from global scope, so `this` was either the window object if you're running in a browser or the global object if you're running in node.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `setInterval(() => this.main(), 5000)` as well.  `this` in JavaScript can differ than what you'd expect the program's source code to suggest. See [MDN's take](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on this.